# Emscripten module in browserify pipeline

Tags: gulp, browserify, amd, emscripten

I'm trying to add an emscripten compiled module in our web site. To achieve this, I'm using browserify (with babelify transformation).

The problem rises when the bundle is created: the emscripten code is wrapped in the resultant js file, but Module is an empty object. The code is actually being parsed, like the following picture shows:
[image: emscripten browserify error]

Long story short:

```
import Module from "./main";
console.log(Module._int_sqrt(9));
```

Returns this error:

```
_main2.default._int_sqrt is not a function
```

I'm working with some restrictions: it's not possible to add the script directly to the html page. The output of this build step must be a single js file including all of its dependencies.

I've created a minimal test case [here](https://bitbucket.org/txusinho/emscripten_browserify_test), so the problem can be replicated by anyone.

I'would appreciate any guidance on this, since I assume it's not a bug in emscripten nor in browserify.

A final remark: the source cpp code works correctly. You can check it running the tests written in mocha.

Comment: I had a similar issue with the uglify npm module, the error was that I had a error code in js and the result was a empty file, check the js file and especially returning literal objects instead of vars, good luck

Comment: If you check the js file, I just import the module, and print the result of the import. The error is nothing related to js itself. The emscripten module is correctly handled in node environent (like mocha test demonstrates). The problem rises from the automatic bundle done by browserify, that detects the environment is a browser, thus I was expecting to behave like a nodejs module (binding itself to module.exports variable)

Comment: What I would make is:
1) compile the module with no optimizations  
2) check which variables are set using browserify  
3) Try to see the flow in the compiled module
4) Are the variables correct?

Comment: 1) no optimizations are set 2)Module is being created, and the run() function is actually invoked 3) The flow is correct, until require [invokes the "main" file](https://bitbucket.org/txusinho/emscripten_browserify_test/src/2c9cca133f59d9daabd261d3a266afae40e903ec/build/bundle.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#bundle.js-420) (referenced by "5")  4) variables are correct, but the closure where they are being evaluated is lost

Answer (score 2):

I was able to come to a solution, thanks to the contributor of the emscripten tool.

The problem is solved if the compilation flag `-s MODULARIZE=1` is added in the emcc compilation phase. Afterwards, in the js code, make an instance of Module. That instance will have the functions accessible.

The js code should look like this:

```
import Module from "./main";

let m = new Module();
console.log(m._int_sqrt(9))
```

I've updated [the test case](https://bitbucket.org/txusinho/emscripten_browserify_test), in case anyone wants to check it

Answer (score 0):

Browserify produced an output that worked for me in Chrome if I forced the Emscripten `Module.ENVIRONMENT = 'NODE'`. This can be done in two ways:

1. Prepend `var Module = { ENVIRONMENT: 'NODE' };` to the Emscripten Javascript output before running browserify.
2. Use the `--pre-js <file>` option of emcc with the file containing the same code as in 1 above.

Comment: I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: Module is not defined` ;c